# Laravel Validation - Exactly one of three must be true?

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm having a bit of a mare working out how to do this in a non-ugly way.

```
['input1'=>true, 'input2'=>false, 'input3'=> false] // valid

['input1'=>false, 'input2'=>false, 'input3'=> false] // not valid
['input1'=>null, 'input2'=>true, 'input3'=> false] // not valid
['input1'=>true, 'input2'=>true, 'input3'=> false] // not valid
```

It seems really simple - the input is only valid if one, and exactly one, of the options is true, while the other two are false (not null).

Can anyone help me make this happen?

(Laravel 5.7 fyi)

Comment: You could look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#using-closures

Comment: Aye - I've looked at that but I can't see how to get the whole input in without triggering a rule/closure on each input field. 0

Answer (score 1):

Solved it eventually.

I needed to override the getValidatorInstance method in a form request:

```
/**
 *  Override the validator instance
 */
protected function getValidatorInstance()
{
    return parent::getValidatorInstance()->after(function ($validator) {

        $trueAttributes = 
            collect(request()->only('input1','input2','input3'))
            ->reject(function($attribute){
                return ($attribute !== true);
            });

        if ($trueAttributes->count() !== 1) {
            $validator->errors()->add('data', 'At least one attribute must be true');
        }
    });
}
```